# Movie where 3 kids visit a museum, travel back in time and meet a baby emperor

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

In the movie there are 3 kids who wander into a museum and find strange things, and there are 3 other kids who are the "villains". The kids time travel back and meet a Chinese emperor, who is a baby and gets a pet from them.

It is animated and the three kids and the other three kids are rivals they race each other to get to the emperor first. I watched it in 2017.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you watch this? Was it animated?  Did all 6 of the kids go back in time together?

Comment: Live action or animated?

Comment: It is Animated And The Three kids and the other three kids are rivals they race each other to get to the emperor first and I watched it in 2017

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the animated film [Guardians of the Lost Code 3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Lost_Code) from 2010 about 3 kids and their fantastical adventure after a trip to the museum. Everything you described is there (including the baby emperor). The trailer:

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH