# Cartoon show or movie involving three kids who combined with monsters to fight three other kids who did likewise

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Years ago when I was little I watched a show or a movie that was three kids and they combined with monsters to fight off three other kids who combined with evil monsters.

There was a scene with a baby and the kids were trying to find a tattoo on the baby and after, I think, a lantern shines on the baby's foot, it reveals a feather tattoo and the tattoo then embeds itself onto the kids. I specifically remember the girl of the group saying “my mom is gonna kill me” and then the tattoo disappears.

The next scene I remember is the three kids falling down a hole or something and, before hitting the ground, they say some usual power of friendship thing and then the tattoo activates. The last thing I remember the six kids teaming up to defeat the main villain at the end.

If you know what this could be, please help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, can you describe what any of the characters looked like (in terms of their sex, hair colour, etc.) and can you describe any of the monsters that they combined with?

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 6):

Is this ***[Guardians of the Lost Code 3D](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1632477/)*** (2010)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Lost_Code):

> *Guardians of the Lost Code* (Spanish: *Brijes 3D*) is a 2010 animated adventure film, created by Ricardo González Duprat, distributed by Videocine.

> During a field trip to the history museum, the students Freddy, Atzi, and Kimo discover a giant stone disk called the Codex in the storage room they are exploring. Three of the brije within it, the deities Quetzalcoatl, Ra and Chu Jung, emerge and reveal to them that they are the three people chosen to restore the ancestral alliance between humans and brijes, an alliance that was fractured with the emergence of science and technology.
>
> The brijes are magical animal spirits that have been in contact with human beings since the beginning of time. Every human had a brije; the human cared for his brije and vice versa. When the human turned 13, a human shaman taught both partners a bonding technique that allowed them to synchronize and transform into a warrior form, gaining extraordinary power allowing them to perform various acts of heroism. Unfortunately, with the birth of modern science and technology, this union was slowly severed as humans stopped believing in magic, leading to tragic results. The brije in the Codex created and sealed themselves within it to protect the knowledge of the warrior form bonding technique from the forces of darkness that seek it.

It's an animated movie about three kids who wander into a storeroom in a history museum and find an ancient stone disc, through which they come into contact with brijes, supernatural creatures they can 'synchronise' with to assume monstrous "warrior forms."

The protagonists are a boy named Freddy, another boy named Kimo, and a girl named Atzi; they're paired with brijes resembling a grasshopper, a chameleon, and a hummingbird, respectively.

The main antagonist is a wealthy, middle-aged man named [Elmer](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Elmer_(Guardians_of_the_Lost_Code)) who recruits three kids to work for him; a boy named [Spikes](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Spikes_(Guardians_of_the_Lost_Code)), a girl named [Muty](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Muty), and another boy named Zejas. Elmer and these three kids all have brijes of their own.

At around the [42:13](https://youtu.be/saDOmJVEjjQ?t=2533) mark, the three protagonists meet a baby emperor with a magical tattoo of a Chinese symbol on his heel, which means "friendship." The same symbol then imprints itself on the foreheads of the three protagonists, and the girl, Atzi, says:

> I didn't want a tattoo until I was eighteen! What will they tell me at home?!

(The symbols disappear a few moments later, though.)

Around the [55:30](https://youtu.be/saDOmJVEjjQ?t=3330) mark, there's a scene where the protagonists undergo a test of character that involves them falling and having to save themselves through the strength of their friendship with one another. We see the symbols that were on their foreheads reappear and glow, and three symbolic feathers are depicted as part of the test.

Finally, toward the end of the film, at around the [1:17:48](https://youtu.be/saDOmJVEjjQ?t=4668) mark, the main antagonist, Elmer, injures Muty, and Spikes and Zejas subsequently team up with the protagonists to defeat him.

Comment: Nice answer! https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/263619/23243 is the current dupe head if so